# Does SOSL works when probabilistic encryption is enabled

Tags: sosl, encryption

Does Salesforce SOSL works after enabling probabilistic encryption is enabled on the search field ?

Comment: Hi Everyone, Any more views on this .. I have enable probabilistic encryption on Account.name and i am able to get the results using SOSL ( not SOQL )           Query : FIND {"google*" } IN Name Fields RETURNING Account(name)                       Any comments ?

Comment: It worked for you probably because "Data that’s already in your org doesn't automatically get encrypted. Our background encryption service takes care of that on request." 
Also, 
"When you turn on encryption for specific fields or other data, newly created and edited data are automatically encrypted with the most recent key." https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_mass_encryption.htm#security_pe_mass_encryption

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't work because each bit of data is turned into a fully random ciphertext string every time it’s encrypted.

Also from Salesforce docs:

> By default, Salesforce encrypts data using a probabilistic encryption
>   scheme. Each bit of data is turned into a fully random ciphertext
>   string every time it’s encrypted. Encryption doesn’t generally impact
>   users who are authorized to view the data. The exceptions are when
>   logic is executed in the database or when encrypted values are
>   compared to a string or to each other. In these cases, because the
>   data has been turned into random, patternless strings, filtering isn’t
>   possible. For example, you might run a SOQL query in custom Apex code
>   against the Contact object, where LastName = 'Smith'. If the LastName
>   field is encrypted with probabilistic encryption, you can’t run the
>   query.

For this we need Deterministic Encryption. 
[How Deterministic Encryption Supports Filtering](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_deterministic_overview.htm)

Comment: thanks for the reply .. i have enable probabilistic encryption on Account.name and i am able to get the results using SOSL ( not SOQL )  FIND {"google*" } IN Name Fields RETURNING Account(name) . I was thinking that with probabilistic encryption, SOSL wont work

Answer (score 0):

NO. See the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_search_encryption_process.htm&type=5) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_deterministic_overview.htm)

Deterministic encryption is an option to allow filtering in SOQL, reports or list views against the data stored in our relational database, and there you only get exact match filtering.

Comment: When we enable Deterministic encryption we can do the search using SOSL instead of SOQL, something like FIND {"google*" } IN Name Fields RETURNING Account(name).